# Use splash from scrapinghub scraping hub locally

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapinghub, splash-js-render

I got a subscription for splash on scrapinghub and I want to use this from a script that is running on my local machine. The instructions I have found so far are:

1. Edit the settings file:

   #I got this one from my scraping hub account
   SPLASH_URL = 'http://xx.x0-splash.scrapinghub.com'

   DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
   'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
   }

   SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
   }

   DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'

   HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'

From that I have one question, when I try to open the splash server on the browser it asks me for a username, I don't see where to set this on scrapy.

[image]

2. the spider file:

   import scrapy
   import json
   from scrapy import  Request
   from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
   import scrapy_splash

   class ListSpider(scrapy.Spider):

   ```
    name = 'list'
    allowed_domains = ['https://medium.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://medium.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        print (response.body)
        with open('data/cookies_file.json') as f:
            cookies_data = json.loads(f.read())[0]
        #print (cookies_data)
        url = 'https://medium.com/' 
        #cookies=cookies_data,
        yield Request(url,  callback=self.afterlogin,meta={'splash': {'args': {'html': 1, 'png': 1,}}})


    def afterlogin(self,response):
        with open(data_dir + 'after_login_page.html','w') as f:
            f.write(str(response.body))
   ```

I'm not getting errors but I'm not sure if splash is working either, also besides the server ip, scraping provides a password which I don't know where to use for this script.

After using splashrequest and adding the API key, This is the traceback of I'm getting, the content of the sites is still not loading.

```
2019-07-17 10:10:08 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-07-17 10:10:08 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-07-17 10:10:08 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-07-17 10:10:09 [scrapy.core.downloader.tls] WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "www.meetmindful.com"; '*.meetmindful.com'!='www.meetmindful.com'
2019-07-17 10:10:09 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.meetmindful.com/> (referer: None)
2019-07-17 10:10:13 [scrapy.core.downloader.tls] WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com"; '*.scrapinghub.com'!='uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com'
2019-07-17 10:10:14 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://app.meetmindful.com/login via https://uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com/render.html> (referer: None)
2019-07-17 10:10:20 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://app.meetmindful.com/grid via https://uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com/render.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
2019-07-17 10:10:21 [scrapy.core.downloader.tls] WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com"; '*.scrapinghub.com'!='uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com'
2019-07-17 10:10:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://app.meetmindful.com/grid via https://uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com/render.html> (referer: None)
2019-07-17 10:10:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-07-17 10:10:26 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 2952,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 28104,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 17, 14, 10, 26, 292646),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'memusage/max': 54104064,
 'memusage/startup': 54104064,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'retry/count': 1,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 2,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 17, 14, 10, 8, 200073)}
2019-07-17 10:10:26 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Edit:

This is the complete log I'm getting;

```
INFO: Scrapy 1.5.2 started (bot: meetmindfull)
INFO: Versions: lxml 4.3.2.0, libxml2 2.9.9, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.20.0, Twisted 19.2.0, Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 22:11:17) - [GCC 7.3.0], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018), cryptography 2.6.1, Platform Linux-4.15.0-20-generic-x86_64-with-debian-buster-sid
INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'meetmindfull', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage', 'LOG_FILE': 'log.txt', 'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'meetmindfull.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['meetmindfull.spiders']}
INFO: Telnet Password: 4a122ec20dcf75e1
INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
INFO: Spider opened
INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "www.meetmindful.com"; '*.meetmindful.com'!='www.meetmindful.com'
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.meetmindful.com/> (referer: None)
WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com"; '*.scrapinghub.com'!='uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com'
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://app.meetmindful.com/login via https://uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com/render.html> (referer: None)
DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://app.meetmindful.com/grid via https://uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com/render.html> (failed 1 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone: Connection was closed cleanly.>]
WARNING: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com"; '*.scrapinghub.com'!='uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com'
DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://app.meetmindful.com/grid via https://uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com/render.html> (referer: None)
INFO: Closing spider (finished)
INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,



'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 2952,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 28096,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 17, 14, 47, 46, 604347),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'memusage/max': 54267904,
 'memusage/startup': 54267904,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'retry/count': 1,
 'retry/reason_count/twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 6,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 6,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 6,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 2,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 17, 14, 47, 28, 791792)}
INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Why not install splash server locally then set SPLASH_URL = localhost

Comment: @PhùngHưngThịnh I'm paying for that service

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Did you use docker on this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into their example file, they have shown how to use it

https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/blob/e40ca4f3b367ab463273bee1357d3edfe0601f0d/example/scrashtest/spiders/quotes.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    allowed_domains = ["toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    # http_user = 'splash-user'
    # http_pass = 'splash-password'

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```

Also you need to yield `SplashRequest` instead of `Request`, you are actually not using Splash at all in your code

```py
yield Request(url,  callback=self.afterlogin,meta={'splash': {'args': {'html': 1, 'png': 1,}}})
```

should be

```py
yield SplashRequest(url,  callback=self.afterlogin,meta={'splash': {'args': {'html': 1, 'png': 1,}}})
```

Comment: I tried that, I get this error: Remote certificate is not valid for hostname "uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com"; '*.scrapinghub.com'!='uyu74ur0-splash.scrapinghub.com

Comment: This is a wild card certificate so the certificate does look ok, can you add exception stack trace to your question?

Comment: I added the response and getting from scrapy

Comment: Can you enable DEBUG logging level and see if you get more details? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html

Comment: I just added it in the question

Comment: Can you also make sure you are using the latest version of Scrapy?

Comment: I'm using  version '1.5.2'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196584/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-luis-ramon-ramirez-rodriguez).